# How to avoid window scrolling after completion list shows up in company-mode?

Tags: window, company-mode, tooltip

When I'm editing a file, if the completion list shows up, the text in the current window will always jump (sometime it will jump a few lines but mostly it will jump to the top of the window), after finishing typing or selecting the right candidate, it will jump back the original place, I got a gif to show what I mean.

[image]

NOTE: this problem cannot be replicated very easily, even by myself, even in the same file. But when I'm editing a source code file or org file, this happens a lot, it's really annoying.

I don't know if it is caused by company itself or not but it only happens in company completion list.

This is my company configuration:

```
(autoload 'company "company" t)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(setq company-global-modes t)
(setq company-tooltip-limit 30)
(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 3)
(setq company-show-numbers t)
(setq company-dabbrev-other-buffers t)
(setq company-transformers '(company-sort-by-occurrence))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c <tab>") 'company-files)
(defalias 'ci 'company-ispell)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (company-mode)
            (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
                 '((
                    company-dabbrev
                    company-dabbrev-code
                    company-ispell
                    company-files
                    company-yasnippet)))))
```

Since the gif is about org-mode, so the last part(`company-backends`) of my configuration snippet here is about `org-mode-hook`

---

**Update**:

After analyzing my whole `init.el`, this problem is caused by [sublimity](https://github.com/zk-phi/sublimity), already posted [an issue](https://github.com/zk-phi/sublimity/issues/21).

Comment: Could you paste your company configuration here? I never get such a long completion popup.

Comment: My company-tooltip-limit is 10, yours seems a little high.

Comment: @stsquad I tried to set the `company-tooltip-limit` to 10, and the auto window-scroll still happens.

Comment: I had [similar issue](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/179) in old Emacs. Probably it is fixed but just to make sure. You should try with bare minimum company configuration to make sure it didn't happen, then adding one by one to see which one caused the issue.

Comment: "adding one by one to see which one caused the issue. " Oh GOD, I hate it when this happens. I'll give it a shot. BTW, it is totally OK with minimum company configuration, and I'm already using v24.4 which is the latest stable version.